# Need to test a variable after switch command

Tags: powershell

I need a way to test that there has been a valid selection and a year level has been properly selected.

I have tried checking with a do/until loop.

```
do{

Function

if($Selection -gt 13)
{write-host "Incorrect year level selection, try again!"
}
    }until ($selection -lt 14)
```

This didn't work.

This is the function that is currently working if a valid response is entered.

```
function Year_Level
{
    $Selection=Read-Host "
    Options
    0 = Reception
    1 = Year 1
    2 = Year 2
    3 = Year 3
    4 = Year 4
    5 = Year 5
    6 = Year 6
    7 = Year 7
    8 = Year 8
    9 = Year 9
    10 = Year 10
    11 = Year 11
    12 = Year 12
    13 = Staff
    Choose a Year Level...."
        Switch ($Selection)
            {
            "R" {$YearLevel1="Year 00"}
            "1" {$YearLevel1="Year 01"}
            "2" {$YearLevel1="Year 02"}
            "3" {$YearLevel1="Year 03"}
            "4" {$YearLevel1="Year 04"}
            "5" {$YearLevel1="Year 05"}
            "6" {$YearLevel1="Year 06"}
            "7" {$YearLevel1="Year 07"}
            "8" {$YearLevel1="Year 08"}
            "9" {$YearLevel1="Year 09"}
            "10" {$YearLevel1="Year 10"}
            "11" {$YearLevel1="Year 11"}
            "12" {$YearLevel1="Year 12"}
            "13" {$YearLevel1="Staff"}
            }
                {
                Return $yearLevel1
                }
}

$year_level = Year_Level

Write-Warning "Year level is $year_level" -Verbose
```

I would like the function to repeat its self until it gets a valid response from the user, therefore, outputting a valid $yearLevel1

Comment: What is `Function` inside your do-while loop?

Comment: That is the year_level function

Comment: @Angas5 - well, it CAN'T work ... you only `function` there and you need to have the function _name_ - `Year_Level` in this case. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

Some Example, i wrote based on your question..hope this helps

```
$a = (1,2) ## these are the only valid responses you can allow

while(1){ ## start loop

    $selection =  Read-Host "Choose your selection"
    $response = switch($selection){

    "1" {"write-host 1 is valid" }

    "2" {"write-host 2 is valid" }
    "default" { "Not a valid reponse" }
    }

    if($a -contains $selection)  { ## if response is valid
    break

    }else{ ## loop for eternity

    Write-Host "Your selection is invalid, you have selected $selection,Please try again"
    }

    }

    Write-Host "Reponse is $response"
```

I have added some comments as well

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach this while keeping your code structure is to utilize recursion and the default case of the switch statement.

```
function Year_Level
{
    $Selection=Read-Host "
    Options
    0 = Reception
    1 = Year 1
    2 = Year 2
    3 = Year 3
    4 = Year 4
    5 = Year 5
    6 = Year 6
    7 = Year 7
    8 = Year 8
    9 = Year 9
    10 = Year 10
    11 = Year 11
    12 = Year 12
    13 = Staff
    Choose a Year Level...."
        Switch ($Selection)
            {
            "R" {$YearLevel1="Year 00"}
            "1" {$YearLevel1="Year 01"}
            "2" {$YearLevel1="Year 02"}
            "3" {$YearLevel1="Year 03"}
            "4" {$YearLevel1="Year 04"}
            "5" {$YearLevel1="Year 05"}
            "6" {$YearLevel1="Year 06"}
            "7" {$YearLevel1="Year 07"}
            "8" {$YearLevel1="Year 08"}
            "9" {$YearLevel1="Year 09"}
            "10" {$YearLevel1="Year 10"}
            "11" {$YearLevel1="Year 11"}
            "12" {$YearLevel1="Year 12"}
            "13" {$YearLevel1="Staff"}
            Default { Year_Level }
            }

         Return $yearLevel1
}

$year_level = Year_Level

Write-Warning "Year level is $year_level" -Verbose
```

When one of the choices is not selected, the function will keep calling itself until a coded case is entered. For example, if the user inputs `16`, the default case will trigger and call the function again. This will repeat forever until one of the other cases is triggered. However, your options list and case statements don't exactly match (see the case of Reception).